# Brainteaser: What is the one thing a queen cannot do that all other pieces can do?

Tags: puzzles

A simple brainteaser - A queen cannot do something all other pieces can do. What is that?

**April 18 2014 9:15 PM GMT. EDIT:** In this context, by "doing" I mean making a move that leads to the desired result.

Comment: Capture a more valuable piece?

Comment: @Akavall, good try, but not quite. Knights can also capture more valuable pieces :)

Comment: Are you asking because you don't know the answer? I have an answer but I don't want to post it and spoil it for others if you are just posting this as a fun brainteaser (in which case I'm not sure it belongs as a question on StackExchange).

Comment: @dfan I do know the answer! Just posting it as a fun brainteaser! :)

Comment: @Wes, The queen is the most powerful piece; therefore, it cannot capture a more valuable piece.

Comment: OK, I won't spoil it for the others.

Comment: @Akavall, oh I see, ok. Maybe in some extremely rare contexts a knight could be more valuable than a queen, so this is still not the exact answer.

Comment: if it is just for fun.. it is a female? it can't do what male can do.. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green, lol!

Comment: Does other pieces include King? For example, let's say for white, white can put Rook or Bishop or Knight on the h3 on the second move, but not the queen. Queen can't get to h3 on 2nd move.

Comment: Yes, the King is included.

Comment: @Akavall The king can't capture a more valuable piece either. :)

Comment: This question seems to be extremely badly worded, as there are 100's of correct, valid answers to this question. "The queen can never start on the opposite color it is, all other pieces can". "The queen can not not be the queen, all other pieces can not be the queen" etc. etc. etc. Questions on SE should as far as I know have a single correct and distinguishable answer. If anything a criterium should be added that the accepted answer will be decided based on popularity or something like on CR.

Comment: @DavidMulder I think "doing" is different from "being" or "having". The mere fact that the queen's starting square is d1 doesn't mean that that is something the queen did. It's funny, but I'm reminded of a batman quote - "It's not who I am underneath, but what I do that defines me" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGGXgjfOWTc

Comment: @Brilliand, True. I missed that :).

Comment: @Wes: Ok, let's be exact then: The queen can not move from a tile [...] in the first turn.

Comment: not sure if this question belongs here.

Comment: There are two things that a queen cannot do. 1. Not fit snugly into the foam lined box cut out perfectly for the queen piece.
2. Fail to give me the most awful gut wrenching feeling when I lose her in exchange for any other piece.

Comment: @Mr_Green what do you mean? all pieces except kings are female. mwahaha https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/gender-of-the-chess-pieces

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll have a go at saying the queen is the only piece that cannot reveal a discovered check.

Comment: This [**blog**](http://scienceblogs.com/evolutionblog/2012/08/23/two-puzzles/) states the same. but I didn't get what it means actually.. any help?

Comment: @Mr_Green Moving the queen cannot cause another piece to give check to the opposing king.

Comment: Some answers are being dismissed with "it isn't the queen itself doing it" - similarly, in the case of discovered check, it's (arguably) more the piece that gives check that's doing something, rather than the piece that's getting out of the way.

Comment: Well, that's why I was sure to specify _reveal_ a discovered check, rather than giving one. :) But yeah, which answers are right is just a matter of definitions really.

Answer (score 11):

1. A Queen cannot be captured when static by an attacking King.
2. A Queen cannot capture a piece more valuable than itself.
3. A Queen cannot move to create a discovered check.
4. A Queen cannot sacrifice itself for a higher valued piece.
5. A Queen cannot initiate a double check.

Comment: 3 and 5 coincide in the case of a queen. For 1, 2, and 4, the same holds true for the King as well.

Comment: @Wes: Double check and discovered check are different.

Comment: I know. That's why I said they coincide in the case of a queen. Every double check is a discovered check.

Comment: Double checks are a pretty interesting case. It's possible to have a double check by two queens with a promotion, but I guess in that case you would say it was initiated by the pawn, even though it became a queen on the same move.

Comment: @AmalMurali I can't think of a double check that isn't a discovered check. For a piece to check something, it either has to move this turn, or discover. Since you can't move more than one piece discovered check is the only way to double check. Thus 5 follows from 3 and is redundant.

Comment: 5. is also true for the king.

Answer (score 7):

The queen **cannot** not be where the queen starts when the game begins.

All other pieces **can** not be where the queen starts when the game begins.

Comment: Although I have an idea why this was downvoted, this is technically true. The queen can in fact not do this, and all other pieces can (in fact, they must).

Comment: It's easy to come up with examples "technically true" for any given piece. Just take a defining property (as the starting position) and say it cannot not have that property, while all others can.

Comment: @FixedPoint: that's not what Cruncher's answer says. Reread it.

Comment: Also, properties are not necessarily something a piece "does". So a queen starting on d1 is not something a queen "did".

Comment: @Wes, answers like this one (and others here) point out that the question itself is rather problematic IMO.

Comment: @EdDean, ok I'll edit it to define what I mean by "doing" I guess.

Answer (score 5):

A queen can not start the game on a square of the other color. All other pieces can, and in fact, do.

Comment: Starting on a square is not something a queen "does".

Comment: Start is a verb, no?

Comment: Not true; the queen's knight, king's bishop, king's rook, queen's rook's pawn, queen's bishop's pawn, king's pawn and king's knight's pawn also cannot start the game on a square of the other colour.

Answer (score 3):

Be the piece that moves away and makes a discovered check!